# Водяные знаки на изображениях в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, изображения

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как реализовать автоматическое установление водяного знака на изображение, загружаемое на сервер в web-приложении на ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вам необходимо получить загружаемое изображение (файл) на стороне сервера:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0].InputStream : Request.InputStream;
```

2) Перевести его в формат изображения:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

3) Далее, делайте с ним все что хотите ([Write Text On An Image in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp) в помощь):

```
using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10)
    {
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
    }
}
```

4) После чего сохраняйте:

```
img.Save(imageFilePath);
```

И никакой магии.